# How to print a file containing a list

Tags: python-3.x

**So basically i have a list in a file and i only want to print the line containing an A**

Here is a small part of the list

```
E5341,21/09/2015,C102,440,E,0
E5342,21/09/2015,C103,290,A,290
E5343,21/09/2015,C104,730,N,0
E5344,22/09/2015,C105,180,A,180
E5345,22/09/2015,C106,815,A,400
```

So i only want to print the line containing A

Sorry im still new at python,
i gave a try using one "print" to print the whole line but ended up failing guess i will always suck at python

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Explain what you have tried and where you have failed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to:

1. open file
2. read lines
3. for each line, split at ","
4. for each line, if the 5th part of the splitted str is equal to "A", print line

**Code:**

```
filepath = 'file.txt'

with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if line.split(',')[4] == "A":
        print(line)
```

Comment: `if line.split(',')[4] == "A":`you should check for equality :)